# Запрет скроллинга страницы в меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, хотел сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на меню оно растягивалось на всю ширину экрана и скролл у страницы полностью запрещался

Так же на некоторых телефонах меню располагается не по центру а где-то с краю, как я показал на скрине ниже

В браузере это работает, а с любого телефона нет, почему так происходит?

Браузер скролл не работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Телефон меню пролистывается вниз: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикладываю HTML, CSS и JS код меню:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {      
     $('.activatemenu').click(function(){
        $('.deactivatemenu').css("position", "absolute");      
        $('.topmenu').animate({ height: "200%"}, 500);
        $('.deactivatemenu').animate({ top: "5%"}, 500);
        $('.activatemenu').fadeOut(250);
        $('.deactivatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
        $("html,body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "5");
     }); 
     $('.deactivatemenu').click(function(){
        $('.topmenu').animate({ height: "3rem"}, 500);
        $('.activatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
        $('.deactivatemenu').fadeOut(250);
        $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
        $("html,body").css("overflow-x","hidden");
        $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "5");
     }); 
  });
```

```css
.topmenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9rem;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: auto;
}
.deactivatemenu {
  display: none;
  left:45%;
  transform:translate(-45%);
  }
.fa-times {
text-decoration: none;
color: #e6e6e6;
position: relative;
}
.mobilemenu {
  display: block;
  color: #e6e6e6 !important;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'oswald', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">
    <div class="topmenu">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="deactivatemenu">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-4">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    <p class="mobiletext">Close</p><br><br>

                            <a href="#home" class="mobilemenu">Home</a><br>
                            <a href="#about" class="mobilemenu">About me</a><br>
                            <a href="#portfolio" class="mobilemenu">Portfolio</a><br>
                            <a href="#comments" class="mobilemenu">Comments</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="activatemenu">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    <p class="mobiletext">Menu</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: У меня 2 вопроса к Вам, 1) обсалютное позиционирование .topmenu Вы от чего делаете?
2) После открытия меню он должен всю страницу закрыть?

Comment: Оно и так закрывает всю страницу, я хочу запретить скроллинг на телефонах, почему-то в браузере он запрещен, а на телефонах в меню скролит

Comment: http://tvarinskydesign.16mb.com/

Можете попробовать зайти с телефона в меню и с браузера, почему-то с браузера скроллинг запрещен, на телефонах листает страницу.

Comment: А `$(window).scroll(function(){return false;});` в нужном месте?

Comment: @EugenEray не совсем понял

Comment: @user234223 Ну типа конструкция: `if(".menu").is(":visible"){$(window).scroll(function(){return false;});} else {$(window).scroll(function(){return true;});}`

Comment: @EugenEray можно взглянуть на это в моём случае?

Comment: как это будет выглядеть, я если честно в js не силён

Answer (score 1):

Ну тогда вот такая поправка в коде и все у вас будет работать на всех устройствах:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {      
  $('.activatemenu').click(function(){
   $('.deactivatemenu').css("position", "absolute");       
   $('.topmenu').animate({ height: "100%"}, 500);
   $('.deactivatemenu').animate({ top: "5%"}, 500);
   $('.activatemenu').fadeOut(250);
   $('.deactivatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
   $("html,body").css("overflow", "hidden");
   $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
   $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
   $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "5");
  }); 
  $('.deactivatemenu').click(function(){
   $('.topmenu').animate({ height: "3rem"}, 500);
   $('.activatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
   $('.deactivatemenu').fadeOut(250);
   $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
   $("html,body").css("overflow-x","hidden");
   $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
   $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
   $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "5");
  }); 
 });
```

```css
  .topmenu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9rem;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: auto;
 }
 .deactivatemenu {
  display: none;
  left:45%;
  transform:translate(-45%);
 }
 .fa-times {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  position: relative;
 }
 .mobilemenu {
  display: block;
  color: #e6e6e6 !important;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'oswald', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topmenu">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
   <div class="deactivatemenu">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    <p class="mobiletext">Close</p>
    <div class="col-xs-12">                 
     <a href="#home" class="mobilemenu">Home</a>
     <a href="#about" class="mobilemenu">About me</a>
     <a href="#portfolio" class="mobilemenu">Portfolio</a>
     <a href="#comments" class="mobilemenu">Comments</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="activatemenu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <p class="mobiletext">Menu</p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Вообще без изменений.

Comment: Проверьте сами на своем девайсе

Comment: Я сделал проверку у себя и все заработало, с этим куском кода, может дело в другом участке кода у вас?

Comment: Я залил изменения с вашими поправками на сайт, а с чем это ещё может быть связано? в JS вроде запрещается скролл страницы, такой вариант тоже не подошел: document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

Comment: А вы уверены что скроллиться body? а не ваше меню?

Comment: Razmik, мне нужно запретить скроллинг на странице в целом пока открыто меню, вот прям на корню отрезать, после того как меню закрывается скроллинг снова разрешить.

Comment: @user234223  position: fixed; Для topmenu сделает его независимым от body и будет во всю ширину и высоту вашего dom документа и вам не надо будет запретить или разрешить скроллинг body в разных случаях.

Comment: @user234223 и в javascript  коде можете стереть те строки где делаете запрет и обратное для скроллинга, а если все ровно не будет работать то отрезьте участок кода вашего меню и тестируете отдельно, увидете что в этом участке кода нет ошибки.